Where do I find the concrete class for the CookieManager?
I'm looking for the concrete class of CookieManager found in the Android Webkit framework. I'm interested of how CookieManager.getInstance.flush() works, since i might have e bug caused by the method.
I've searched here Android Code Search repository but only found concrete classes of CookieManager for testing, using Roboelectric.

